# Error compiling java code generated by Ragel 6.7

Tags: java, compiler-construction, ragel

I'm trying to use Ragel to write a simple Lexer, and output it to Java valid code, but the generated code does not compile.

Here's the Lexer.rl that I'm using:

```
public class Lexer {
    %%{
      machine simple_lexer;

      integer     = ('+'|'-')?[0-9]+;
      float       = ('+'|'-')?[0-9]+'.'[0-9]+;
      assignment  = '=';
      identifier  = [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_]+; 

      main := |*
        integer => { emit("integer"); };
        float => { emit("float"); };
        assignment => { emit("assignment"); };
        identifier => { emit("identifier"); };
        space => { emit("space"); };
      *|;

    }%%

    %% write data;

    public static void emit(String token) {
        System.out.println(token);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        %% write init;

        %% write exec;
    }
}
```

The generated file and the error output are in: https://gist.github.com/3495276 (because it's too large to paste here =S )

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of Ragel do you use? The line 143 looks strange: `4`. I don't get this "4" when using latest ragel 6.7

Comment: I'm currently using Ragel 6.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare certain variables that will be used in the generated code. Refer to the section 5.1 "Variables used by Ragel" of user guide.

`main` should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int cs; /* state number */
    char[] data = "xy = 22 wq = 11.46".toCharArray(); /* input */
    int p = 0, /* start of input */
        pe = data.length, /* end of input */
        eof = pe,
        ts, /* token start */
        te, /* token end */
        act /* used for scanner backtracking */;

    %% write init;

    %% write exec;
}
```

Also, not sure if you really want identifiers to be at least two symbols long.

```
identifier  = [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_]+;
```

probably should be

```
identifier  = [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_]*;
```